# Should I use Client credential flows for enabling Microsoft Graph API for my webapp that has a module to get list of conference rooms?

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar, hosted-blazor-webassembly

We're working on a web app that will be used by a specific client. One of their requests is that the app should only work for their organization. We've set up authentication using asp.net identity. Now, for a particular feature, we need to fetch a list of conference rooms within their organization and know if these rooms are available.

I'm considering using the Client Credential Flow to enable the Microsoft Graph API, which would allow us to retrieve the list of rooms and their availability. Does this seem like the right way to go?

I know that it requires configuration & admin consent for initial setup.

Let me know your thoughts and if you need more details.

Note: We simply need a module that can retrieve conference room details for the company and indicate room availability (However, this should only work for that specific organization; individuals from personal or different organizations should not be able to access it.)

Comment: Don't discount Blazor 8 because it comes out in November 2023 as a Long-Term Support version. The latest preview added [Auto render mode](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-dotnet-8-preview-7/#auto-render-mode) that decides whether to use client or server rendering based on network speed. The October if not September release will be a Go Live one

Comment: Thanks for the info i checked out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QD2-DwuOfKM and its mind-blowing. Blazor SSR is the best solution, no bulky blazor wasm or no leggy blazor server. 

I just created a demo project with "blazor web app" and its fast, but when I stoped the debugging mode, it got the same message like we get for blazor server apps. Is it still using signal r in backend? If yes then I think it might have latency issue like blazor serve. Can you please clarify on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For enabling Ms Graph API into your application, you have to implement the authentication, for client credential flow, you need Azure AD app + correct API permission + admin consent. But for some other common flow such as auth code flow, you also need to integrate Ms indentity in your application so that users could sign in with their microsoft account and get authorized to call Ms Graph API, while client credential flow doesn't demand the user-sign-in operation.

In your scenario, you already have asp.net core identity, it looks like you don't have specific requirement to add another authentication scheme. Therefore, the client credential flow looks the best option for you.

Let's see [the authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#first-case-access-token-request-with-a-shared-secret) for client credential flow, what you need is client id, client secret, and the scope is always `http://graph.microsoft.com/.default`.

```
POST /{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1           //Line breaks for clarity
Host: login.microsoftonline.com:443
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=535fb089-9ff3-47b6-9bfb-4f1264799865
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
&client_secret=sampleCredentia1s
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

And for [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-access-token-with-a-client_secret), you have to sign in first to get the auth code, then you could use auth code to generate the access token and use it to call graph API.

get auth code:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&response_mode=query
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read
&state=12345
&code_challenge=YTFjNjI1OWYzMzA3MTI4ZDY2Njg5M2RkNmVjNDE5YmEyZGRhOGYyM2IzNjdmZWFhMTQ1ODg3NDcxY2Nl
&code_challenge_method=S256
```

get access token with auth code:

```
POST /{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: https://login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read
&code=OAAABAAAAiL9Kn2Z27UubvWFPbm0gLWQJVzCTE9UkP3pSx1aXxUjq3n8b2JRLk4OxVXr...
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&grant_type=authorization_code
&code_verifier=ThisIsntRandomButItNeedsToBe43CharactersLong 
&client_secret=JqQX2PNo9bpM0uEihUPzyrh    // NOTE: Only required for web apps. This secret needs to be URL-Encoded.
```

By the way, I noticed you have a blazor-web-assembly tag in your question, if this is the project where you want to add graph API code in, you are not allowed to use client credential flow, because this is a client app while client credential flow is only support in a daemon application like web api or blazor server app. You have to integrating microsoft identity and use the auth code flow. For blazor web assembly integrating Azure AD and calling Graph API, you might refer to [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-blazor-wasm/blob/main/WebApp-graph-user/Call-MSGraph/README.md).

==============================================

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();

//CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddCookie(x => x.LoginPath = "/account/login");
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"), OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, "ADCookies");

// Add microsoft identity ui would make you have a LoginPartial view and we could modify this view to add asp.net core identity sign in
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

and then in the view, we might integrating both of the authentication scheme with 2 groups of buttons.

```
@using System.Security.Principal

<ul class="navbar-nav">
    @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        <li class="nav-item">
            <span class="navbar-text text-dark">Hello @User.Identity.Name!</span>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="LogOut">log out</a>
        </li>
        @*asp - area = "MicrosoftIdentity"*@
    }
    else
    {
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login">log in</a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>

@*<ul class="navbar-nav">
    @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        <li class="nav-item">
            <span class="navbar-text text-dark">Hello @User.Identity.Name!</span>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignOut">Sign out</a>
        </li>
    }
    else
    {
        <li>user is : @User.Identity.Name  + @User.Identity.IsAuthenticated</li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignIn">Sign in</a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>*@
```

Finally we need to keep the user in Azure AD and the user in our own database having mapping relationship, or in other words, I have an account with @xx.onmicrosoft.com and another account with @xxx.com, but the application should know both of the accounts are mine.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It's a Blazor WebAssembly ASP.NET Core Blazor hosted. I'll be implementing the client credential flow within the service, which will then provide data to the UI through API controller.

I am now a little confused after you guys mentioned delegated permissions. Initially we wanted to implement both ASP.NET identity and azure AD for company tenant but I couldn't find any tutorial to use it in combination.

We just want a module to get list of conference and its schedule that is going to be deployed in a company and to be used by that company only.

Comment: it's true that we don't have official documents for both integrating AAD and asp.net core identity. I test before but it didn't look good. Anyway when we need custom implement. For the `delegated` API permission, it's used for a user, which means the project should integrating AAD so that user could sign in, then calling api could use delegated permission, which means the app is calling api on behalf of you. While `application` API permission doesn't require user sign in, and calling api on behalf of the application.  you had asp.net core hosted application,  client credential flow is ok

Comment: Aww man, after you mention "authentication scheme" I tried searching on how to implement multiple authentication scheme but couldn't find what I was looking for. And now I am convinced that for our module's requirement "application" permission is the perfect fit (because every user might have different access and we just need a module to display all rooms and their availability which shouldn't depend on user). Thanks for a lot. But I like "Arvind Suthar's" idea to create another app register for azure ad auth, if we decided to use it in future.. What do you think about it?

Comment: yes, now you just need a module which loading all the rooms and their availability, so using client credential flow is suitable for you now because it won't influence your project except creating a new cs file and adding a new method to get API response. and whenever you want to integrate AAD authentication into your app as well, it's better for you to have a new AAD app. Just like you said for different users they might have different permissions, and when you are using application permission in the AAD app, it would have a very "big" permission comparing with delegated API permission.

Comment: and for `implement multiple authentication scheme`, maybe you can take a look at my work before, I'm not sure if it's a good option and I'm sure I have't completed it all.

Comment: Thanks for the example got a general idea where to head, but it looks like its for MVC, its very tricky for blazor WASM. Because our session is managed by .net server side in MVC but in blazor wasm we have to maintain it in client side by using token storing and retrieval. Check out this one https://code-maze.com/dotnet-multiple-authentication-schemes/ . Its cool but its for API and not blazor :( Maybe I have to use some library like OpenIDDict https://damienbod.com/2023/02/14/use-multiple-identity-providers-from-a-blazor-wasm-asp-net-core-app-secured-using-bff/

Comment: yes it's just an idea, because I also didn't find any official document for both using AAD auth and asp.net core default auth...

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm. Tiny Wang's answer *sounds* great... but if you only want people who actually have permissions to a company's resources (conference rooms in this case) you would be better off using *delegated* permissions rather than *app* permissions so your application would operate using the permissions of the logged in user.

*"In the client credentials flow, permissions are granted directly to the application itself by an administrator. When the app presents a token to a resource, the resource enforces that the app itself has authorization to perform an action since there is no user involved in the authentication."*

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow

Comment: We already have ASP.net identity in place, we tried to implement both together but couldn't find any good tutorial for it. So we decided to check other flow and "Client Credential Flow" sounded better.

What if logged in user don't have enough privilege to see all conference rooms?

Comment: If you want the app to have more permissions than the logged in user, then yes, app permissions and the client credentials grant is the right approach. And you *can* do your own authorization check of the user with ASP.NET Identity (with a credential you issue) to ensure only the right users are getting access to the conf room info. However, the credentials the user uses with ASP.NET Identity won’t be their O365 credentials. To achieve SSO and not introduce another username/password for users, you *could* register a second app ID to perform user authentication for the user authorization check.

Comment: Using second app register for auth sounds like a good idea but do you know how to implement both at same time? ASP.NET identity and azure ad?

Comment: Seems this StackOverflow user had the same problem and posted a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72208260/problems-using-microsoft-identity-web-app-and-microsoft-aspnetcore-identity-in-t

Comment: Thanks Arvind, but the problem is I am using blazor webassembly. It requires additional logic in client side for storing and retrieving token etc... He used blazor server :(

Thanks for sharing that link

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use the user's already existing Azure AD credentials? If they are interested in O365 conference rooms, they presumably already have Azure AD credentials. This way, you could use Microsoft Identity Web for both user and app authentication. And - bonus - not manage extra credentials for your users.

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what I had in mind. But now it will depends on customer's requirement, will give me options and let him decide. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If a user is running the app, you should use Delegated permissions. If the script is ran by an automated process such as Power Automate you should use app-only permissions.

Please see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts#access-scenarios

Comment: We need to fetch conference room list along with its availability for entire organization. Which I don't think all users will have similar privilege. Its not a script but a API endpoint that is accessed by logged (Basic auth) in user.
"It's suitable when it's undesirable to have a user signed in, or when the data required can't be scoped to a single user."